# Accessing passed variable from Visualforce page OR pass Controller.addFields in TEST

Tags: soql, apex-variable

I want to pass the pricebook2id from an opportunity to my apex class and then use this when querying.
I can get it using the Controller.addFields when declaring the controller like this:

```
public AddProduct(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
Controller.addFields(new List<String>{'Name', 'PriceBook2Id'});
}
```

But then I have issues passing the test.

So how do I properly use this information in the query in the method to add a Opportunityproduct aka method AddJuice?

Here is the relevant visualforce page info with the passed variable attempt:

```
<apex:page  standardController="Opportunity"  extensions="MyExtension" >
 <apex:outputField value = "{!Opportunity.Pricebook2id}" rendered="false"/>
 <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock title="Add Opportunity Product" >
   <apex:commandButton action="{!AddJuice}" value="Add Juice" />
   <apex:commandButton action="{!AddMilk}" value="Add Milk" />
  </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

Here is my extension class:

```
 public class myextension {

        private ApexPages.StandardController sc;
        public String PassedPricebookId {
                get {
                    return String.valueOf(Opportunity.Pricebook2id.id);
                        }
                private set;
              }
 system.debug(OppPBId);

 public AddProduct(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
                sc= controller;
                ELI = new OpportunityLineItem();
                CusLI = new OpportunityLineItem();
               if (!Test.isRunningTest()) Controller.addFields(new List<String>{'Name', 'PriceBook2Id'}); //-- this can work but won't pass test!
            }

  public PageReference AddJuice (){
                Opportunity TheOpp = (Opportunity)sc.GetRecord();
                ELI.OpportunityId=TheOpp.id;
                ELI.PricebookEntryId=[select id from PricebookEntry 
                where name =: 'Juice' 
                and Pricebook2id=:(how do I get the PassedPricebookId in here?].id;
        //more fields etc

              PageReference ScheduleUrl = new PageReference
             ('/oppitm/scheduleedit.jsp?id='+ELi.id+'&sUrl=%2F'+ELi.id+'&retURL=%2F'+TheOpp.id);
        return ScheduleUrl;
            }
```

Secondary question - why does my line system.debug(OppPBId); throw an error:

> unexpected token: ')'

Comment: can you post more VFP code on what basis you want to pass value to controller, like any field selection or changing any values from VFP

Comment: sure, more added

Comment: can you post your test class code and let us know what issue you are facing

Comment: I am having issue where I can't set the Pricebook2id for the op. I have a processBuilder that sets it in prod but it is not setting. And when I try to declare it, it returns no rows and errors, even though the same query in the query editor returns a valid Pricebookid

Comment: check my answer, not sure it helps, because your question is still confusing to me as to how you are setting the pricebookId and how you are accessing.

Comment: refer my answer with updated test classes, I could understand you are facing issues in writing test methods with Opportunity and PriceBookEntry

Answer (score 3):

I have made small changes in the Extension class.

Added `TheOpp = (Opportunity)sc.getRecord();` in the Constructor.

```
public class myextension {

    private ApexPages.StandardController sc;
    public Opportunity TheOpp{get;set;}

    public String PassedPricebookId {
            get {
                return String.valueOf(TheOpp.Pricebook2id); //take from Controller TheOpp
            }
            private set;
          }

    public AddProduct(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        sc= controller;
        TheOpp = (Opportunity)sc.getRecord(); //initialize TheOpp

        ELI = new OpportunityLineItem();
        CusLI = new OpportunityLineItem();
       if (!Test.isRunningTest()) Controller.addFields(new List<String>{'Name', 'PriceBook2Id'}); //-- this can work but won't pass test!
    }

  public PageReference AddJuice (){
        ELI.OpportunityId=TheOpp.id;
        ELI.PricebookEntryId=[select id from PricebookEntry 
        where name =: 'Juice' 
        and Pricebook2id=:PassedPricebookId;
        //more fields etc

      PageReference ScheduleUrl = new PageReference
     ('/oppitm/scheduleedit.jsp?id='+ELi.id+'&sUrl=%2F'+ELi.id+'&retURL=%2F'+TheOpp.id);
        return ScheduleUrl;
     }
}
```

Change the Visualforce

```
<apex:outputField value = "{!TheOpp.Pricebook2id}" rendered="false"/>
```

It is still confusing to me `PassedPricebookId` property. I could assume it will take from Opportunity itself.

and this line

```
if (!Test.isRunningTest()) Controller.addFields(new List<String>{'Name', 'PriceBook2Id'});
```

Given an approach how you can create test records for Opportunity and PriceBook in test class. *You could change based on your need.*

```
@isTest
public class OpportunityExtnTest {
    // Utility method that can be called by Apex tests to create price book entries.
    static testmethod void AddJuiceTesting() {
        // First, set up test price book entries.
        // Insert a test product.
        Product2 prod = new Product2(Name = 'Laptop X200', 
            Family = 'Hardware');
        insert prod;

        // Get standard price book ID.
        // This is available irrespective of the state of SeeAllData.
        Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

        // 1. Insert a price book entry for the standard price book.
        // Standard price book entries require the standard price book ID we got earlier.
        PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(Name='Juice',
            Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, Product2Id = prod.Id,
            UnitPrice = 10000, IsActive = true);
        insert standardPrice;

        //Create Account
        Account acct = new Account(Name='TestAccount1');
        insert acct;

        //now create Opportunity with PriceBookId
        Opportunity oppty = new Opportunity(Name='TestOppty', AccountId=acct.id, Pricebook2Id=pricebookId);
        insert oppty;

        //now create OpportunityLineItems
        OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId = oppty.Id, Product2Id = prod.Id);
        insert oli;

        //now pass value to Controller.
        //create pageReference
        PageReference page = Page.MyVFP;
        Test.setCurrentPage(page);

        //pass parameter to the page
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',oppty.Id);

        //create an instance of controller.
        ApexPages.StandardController standrdcontroller = new ApexPages.StandardController(oppty);
        myextension myextensionObj = new myextension(standrdcontroller);

        myextensionObj.AddJuice();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ELI.PricebookEntryId = [select id from PricebookEntry 
                where name =: 'Juice' 
                and Pricebook2Id = :TheOpp.Pricebook2Id];
```

Also you can't put `system.debug`'s in the area where you are declare your member variables.  Put it inside a function or a get/set method.  OppPBId is a variable that doesn't exist anywhere, so it will still throw you another error saying the variable doesn't exist even after you put it in a function.

Comment: If I use this, I need to use Controller.addFields(new List<String>{'Name', 'PriceBook2Id'}); and then that can't pass Test

Comment: Your test class should look like this: `Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Pricebook2Id = <id of pricebook2id>); MyExtension controller = new MyExtension(new ApexPages.StandardController(opp));`

Comment: I am not geting a pass on the test run - myExtension controller = new MyExtension(new ApexPages.StandardController(opp));
        controller.AddJuice();  - can you put the test info in your answer? Am told query has no rows for assignment but buttons work in prod

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is just getting 100% test coverage, you will never be able to do it with the `addFields()` method in your code.

The work around is to include the fields in you visualforce page, even if you aren't rendering them.

```
<apex:page  standardController="Opportunity"  extensions="MyExtension" >
 <apex:outputField value = "{!Opportunity.Pricebook2id}" rendered="false"/>
 <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock title="Add Opportunity Product" >
   <apex:commandButton action="{!AddJuice}" value="Add Juice" />
   <apex:commandButton action="{!AddMilk}" value="Add Milk" />
  </apex:pageBlock>
 <apex:outputField value="{!Name}" rendered="false" />
 <apex:outputField value="{!PriceBook2Id}" rendered="false" />
 </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

Although if you would prefer to leave the `addFields()` method as it is, you could just chalk this up to a deficiency in the testing framework and leave it as less than 100% test coverage.

---

As for the `PassedPricebookId` class attribute,

```
return String.valueOf(Opportunity.Pricebook2id.id);
```

should just be

```
return String.valueOf(Opportunity.Pricebook2Id);
// or just // return Opportunity.Pricebook2Id;
```

The reason is that the Pricebook2Id field is itself an `Id`.

Comment: I have terrible coverage right now...  I like the method you describe but I am keep being unable to use the passed Pricebook2id in my methods - please see my code where  I have (how do I get the PassedPricebookId in here?]